# Renew certificate with Java Keytool - reuse old CSR?

Tags: java, certificate, keytool

I have an SSL certificate in a Java keystore.  It's going to expire in a week or so and I need to renew it.

Can I reuse the previous CSR (which the CA still have) and then import the certificate using the `import` command or do I need to generate a new CSR?

Comment: If today is Jan1,2011 and I use a CSR dated from Jan 31,2010, will the cert reply work for 1 month or one year?

Comment: @djangofan - You'd be more likely to get a response if you asked that as a question.  I don't have the answer, I'm afraid :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can (if your CA doesn't check for public key reuse), but it's a bad security practice. The primary purpose of the validity period is to limit the time in which a certificate and associated private key is exposed to the possibility of being compromised.

Comment: So I should really generate a new set of keys, then?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, generate a new keypair and associated CSR.

Comment: You guys might be able to help me.  I'm referencing your question/answer in my new question.  I'm a little stuck.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420459/commands-to-renew-a-java-keystore-with-a-symantec-renewal-using-a-new-csr